# Kivy layout positioning problems - not understanding/properly using __init__, kv, kv properties

Tags: python, kivy

I am a new programmer (and first time stackoverflow poster) so please correct me if I use terminology incorrectly or make any other missteps in etiquette or proper coding style.

I am trying to write a game where you draw tiles to your tile rack and then play them on a board. I have already written a game that works without graphics via text input. Now I would like to use Kivy to make a graphical interface.

One of my problems involves the positioning of widgets. I would like to center my rack widget at the center of the screen x-axis. I can have it draw a rectangle there and have it appear to be positioned where I want it, but its x position is (as you might guess) 0. I think part of my problem is that I have passed a Game object to my widget and using a list of symbols (game.symbols) and an **init** method, I tried to load create tile widgets with a label(text=symbol) and then load them on the rack. As you probably have guessed, my tiles also are not positioned correctly.

1. How can I center my tile rack and load my tiles correctly so they have the proper position (which I think is necessary for my collision detection).
2. Please explain the way **init** method and the KV file are executed when both are used.
3. What is the proper way to pass objects and attributes to widgets in regards to my issues here. Should I have created an ObjectProperty?

I also may just have a fundamental misunderstanding of positioning and layouts in Kivy and if so, please educate me.

Thank you,
Cliff

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label

kv_Game= '''
<TileWidget>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 50,50
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5,0.5,1,0.3
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width, self.height

    canvas.after:
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            dash_offset: 5
            dash_length: 3

<RackWidget>:

    size_hint: None, None
    size: 350, 50
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
    y: 75

    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,0.5
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
'''

Builder.load_string(kv_Game)

class Game(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.symbols = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&']
        self.rackWidget = RackWidget(self)
        self.add_widget(self.rackWidget)

class TileWidget(Scatter):

    def __init__(self, symbol="?", **kwargs):
        super(TileWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        tileLabel = Label(text=symbol, size_hint=(None,None), size=(50,50))
        self.add_widget(tileLabel)

class RackWidget(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, game, **kwargs):
        super(RackWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("TileRackWidget pos:", self.pos)

        x, y = self.pos
        for symbol in game.symbols:
            tileWidget = TileWidget(symbol=symbol, pos= (x,y))
            self.add_widget(tileWidget)
            print("tileWidget pos:", tileWidget.pos)
            x+=50

class GameTest1App(App):
    def build(self):

        game = Game()
        return game

if __name__=="__main__":
    GameTest1App().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pos` is not set to a usable value yet when you create your `RackWidget` instance. When `__init__` is running, the widget has not yet been added to the `Game` widget, so it has no parent and no positioning information. You could solve this by binding to the changes in `RackWidget.pos`, but there's an easier way to do this: [`RelativeLayout`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html). The position of each child of a `RelativeLayout` will be based on the position of the layout itself.

Here's a modified version of `RackWidget` using `RelativeLayout`:

```
class RackWidget(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, game, **kwargs):
        super(RackWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("TileRackWidget pos:", self.pos)

        x, y = 0, 0
        for symbol in game.symbols:
            tileWidget = TileWidget(symbol=symbol, pos= (x,y))
            self.add_widget(tileWidget)
            print("tileWidget pos:", tileWidget.pos)
            x+=50
```

Comment: Thanks!
Definitely better.However, the positions that are printed are now associated with the RelativeLayout, including that of the TileRackWidget. I can understand the tiles being relative to its parent, but the rack is also positioned relative to itself?: 

TileRackWidget pos: [0, 75]
tileWidget pos: (0.0, 0.0)
tileWidget pos: (50.0, 0.0)
tileWidget pos: (100.0, 0.0)
tileWidget pos: (150.0, 0.0)
tileWidget pos: (200.0, 0.0)
tileWidget pos: (250.0, 0.0)
tileWidget pos: (300.0, 0.0)

This gave me problems when I was using collide_widget. Perhaps the binding that your proposed is the way to go?

Comment: Oh, it's the same issue I think. I would be interested in how one would do it properly with binding within the init if you have a moment.

Comment: You can use `Widget.to_window(*pos)` to get coordinates relative to the window based on the Widget.